# How to adjust power requirements for a propeller working against a pressure head

Tags: fluid-dynamics, pressure

I'm in the process of building a hovercraft. In order to lift it, I'll need a motor directing the flow of air into a skirt. The specs for the motor I'm looking at say that it can turn a 15x5 dual-blade propeller at 6,000 RPM with 262W of power.

However, the motor is designed to be used by a large drone. In that case, the motor only has to work against atmospheric pressure. My hovercraft will have about .17 psi of pressure within the skirt. How do I adjust the required power for a given RPM based on the pressure below the propeller?